# sqlalchemy orm column name convention

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I automatically map all of my fields of the forms `my_column` to corresponding columns `MyColumn` in the database?

```
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'MyTable'
    # what I have now:
    my_column_1 = Column('MyColumn1', Integer)
    # what I want: how to configure a convention mapping rule for this:
    my_column_1 = Column(Integer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide your own metaclass that renames columns, before passing control to `DeclarativeMeta`. Another option would be to alter column names in a [`before_parent_attach`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.DDLEvents.before_parent_attach) event handler for [`Column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column), but that would affect all columns globally, compared to just the ones in mapped classes using a specific declarative base.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api import DeclarativeMeta
from sqlalchemy import Column

class RenamingDeclarativeMeta(DeclarativeMeta):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        _rename_declared_columns(namespace)
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)

    def __setattr__(cls, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, Column):
            _undefer_column_name_only(key, value)
        super().__setattr__(key, value)

def to_camelcase(s):
    return ''.join([w.title() for w in s.split('_')])

def _undefer_column_name_only(key, column):
    if column.name is None:
        column.name = to_camelcase(key)

def _rename_declared_columns(namespace):
    for key, attr in namespace.items():
        if isinstance(attr, Column):
            _undefer_column_name_only(key, attr)
```

This omits some functionality, such as renaming columns contained in `ColumnProperty` and `CompositeProperty` attributes. In order to use it pass it as the [`metaclass`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base.params.metaclass) to [`declarative_base()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base):

```
In [2]: from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

In [3]: Base = declarative_base(metaclass=RenamingDeclarativeMeta)

In [4]: from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer

In [5]: class Foo(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'foo'
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     bar_baz_1 = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
   ...:     

In [6]: Foo.id
Out[6]: <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute at 0x7ffb7f770e60>

In [7]: Foo.bar_baz_1
Out[7]: <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute at 0x7ffb7dc47200>

In [8]: list(Foo.__table__.columns)
Out[8]: 
[Column('Id', Integer(), table=<foo>, key='id', primary_key=True, nullable=False),
 Column('BarBaz1', Integer(), table=<foo>, key='bar_baz_1', nullable=False)]
```

---

The other approach would be to globally rename all columns that are attached to [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) objects using the [event API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html):

```
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Column, 'before_parent_attach')
def receive_column_before_table_attach(column, table):
    # As dumb as it gets. Blindly modifies all columns.
    column.name = to_camelcase(column.name)
```

This has a *major* drawback: it will blindly rename columns in reflected tables as well, which is why I'd recommend using the metaclass approach. It's better contained and is less surprising.

Comment: I'm actually interested in the solution that affects all columns globally, since I'm trying to map to a database created from ASP.NET EntityFramework. For completeness, could you please include the solution using `before_parent_attach`?